# Multiple nested request with scrapy

Tags: nested, scrapy

I try to scrap some airplane schedule information on www.flightradar24.com website for research project.

The hierarchy of json file i want to obtain is something like that :

```
Object ID
 - country
   - link
   - name
   - airports
     - airport0 
       - code_total
       - link
       - lat
       - lon
       - name
       - schedule
          - ...
          - ...
      - airport1 
       - code_total
       - link
       - lat
       - lon
       - name
       - schedule
          - ...
          - ...
```

`Country` and `Airport` are stored using items, and as you can see on json  file the `CountryItem` (link, name attribute) finally store multiple `AirportItem` (code_total, link, lat, lon, name, schedule) :

```
class CountryItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    airports = scrapy.Field()
    other_url= scrapy.Field()
    last_updated = scrapy.Field(serializer=str)

class AirportItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    code_little = scrapy.Field()
    code_total = scrapy.Field()
    lat = scrapy.Field()
    lon = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    schedule = scrapy.Field()
```

Here my scrapy code `AirportsSpider` to do that :

```
class AirportsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "airports"
    start_urls = ['https://www.flightradar24.com/data/airports']
    allowed_domains = ['flightradar24.com']

    def clean_html(self, html_text):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')
        return soup.get_text()

    rules = [
    # Extract links matching 'item.php' and parse them with the spider's method parse_item
        Rule(LxmlLinkExtractor(allow=('data/airports/',)), callback='parse')
    ]


    def parse(self, response):
        count_country = 0
        countries = []
        for country in response.xpath('//a[@data-country]'):
            if count_country > 5:
                break
            item = CountryItem()
            url =  country.xpath('./@href').extract()
            name = country.xpath('./@title').extract()
            item['link'] = url[0]
            item['name'] = name[0]
            count_country += 1
            countries.append(item)
            yield scrapy.Request(url[0],meta={'my_country_item':item}, callback=self.parse_airports)

    def parse_airports(self,response):
        item = response.meta['my_country_item']
        airports = []

        for airport in response.xpath('//a[@data-iata]'):
            url = airport.xpath('./@href').extract()
            iata = airport.xpath('./@data-iata').extract()
            iatabis = airport.xpath('./small/text()').extract()
            name = ''.join(airport.xpath('./text()').extract()).strip()
            lat = airport.xpath("./@data-lat").extract()
            lon = airport.xpath("./@data-lon").extract()

            iAirport = AirportItem()
            iAirport['name'] = self.clean_html(name)
            iAirport['link'] = url[0]
            iAirport['lat'] = lat[0]
            iAirport['lon'] = lon[0]
            iAirport['code_little'] = iata[0]
            iAirport['code_total'] = iatabis[0]

            airports.append(iAirport)

        for airport in airports:
            json_url = 'https://api.flightradar24.com/common/v1/airport.json?code={code}&plugin\[\]=&plugin-setting\[schedule\]\[mode\]=&plugin-setting\[schedule\]\[timestamp\]={timestamp}&page=1&limit=50&token='.format(code=airport['code_little'], timestamp="1484150483")
            yield scrapy.Request(json_url, meta={'airport_item': airport}, callback=self.parse_schedule)

        item['airports'] = airports

        yield {"country" : item}

    def parse_schedule(self,response):

        item = response.request.meta['airport_item']
        jsonload = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        json_expression = jmespath.compile("result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule")
        item['schedule'] = json_expression.search(jsonload)
```

Explanation :

- In my first parse, i call a request on for each country link i found whith the `CountryItem` created via `meta={'my_country_item':item}`. Each of these request callback `self.parse_airports`
- In my second level of parse `parse_airports`, i catch `CountryItem` created using `item = response.meta['my_country_item']` and i create a new item `iAirport = AirportItem()` for each airport i found into this country page. Now i want to get `schedule` information for each `AirportItem` created and stored in `airports` list.
- In the second level of parse `parse_airports`, i run a for loop on `airports` to catch `schedule` information using a new Request. Because i want to include this schedule information into my AirportItem, i include this item into meta information `meta={'airport_item': airport}`. The callback of this request run `parse_schedule`
- In the third level of parse `parse_schedule`, i inject the schedule information collected by scrapy into the AirportItem previously created using `response.request.meta['airport_item']`

But i have a problem in my source code, scrapy correctly scrap all the informations (country, airports, schedule), but my comprehension of nested item seems not correct. As you can see the json i produced contain `country > list of (airport)`, but not `country > list of (airport > schedule )`

[image]

My code is on github : https://github.com/IDEES-Rouen/Flight-Scrapping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you fork your item, where according to your logic you only want 1 item per country, so you can't yield mutltiple items at any point after parsing the country. What you want to do is stack all of them into one item.
To do that you need to create a parsing loop:

```
def parse_airports(self, response):
    item = response.meta['my_country_item']
    item['airports'] = []

    for airport in response.xpath('//a[@data-iata]'):
        url = airport.xpath('./@href').extract()
        iata = airport.xpath('./@data-iata').extract()
        iatabis = airport.xpath('./small/text()').extract()
        name = ''.join(airport.xpath('./text()').extract()).strip()
        lat = airport.xpath("./@data-lat").extract()
        lon = airport.xpath("./@data-lon").extract()

        iAirport = dict()
        iAirport['name'] = 'foobar'
        iAirport['link'] = url[0]
        iAirport['lat'] = lat[0]
        iAirport['lon'] = lon[0]
        iAirport['code_little'] = iata[0]
        iAirport['code_total'] = iatabis[0]
        item['airports'].append(iAirport)

    urls = []
    for airport in item['airports']:
        json_url = 'https://api.flightradar24.com/common/v1/airport.json?code={code}&plugin\[\]=&plugin-setting\[schedule\]\[mode\]=&plugin-setting\[schedule\]\[timestamp\]={timestamp}&page=1&limit=50&token='.format(
            code=airport['code_little'], timestamp="1484150483")
        urls.append(json_url)
    if not urls:
        return item

    # start with first url
    next_url = urls.pop()
    return Request(next_url, self.parse_schedule,
                   meta={'airport_item': item, 'airport_urls': urls, 'i': 0})

def parse_schedule(self, response):
    """we want to loop this continuously for every schedule item"""
    item = response.meta['airport_item']
    i = response.meta['i']
    urls = response.meta['airport_urls']

    jsonload = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    item['airports'][i]['schedule'] = 'foobar'
    # now do next schedule items
    if not urls:
        yield item
        return
    url = urls.pop()
    yield Request(url, self.parse_schedule,
                  meta={'airport_item': item, 'airport_urls': urls, 'i': i + 1})
```

Comment: Hi Granitosaurus, i try the code after some minor typo correction, but any Item is written by pipeline.

Comment: @reyman64 hey, I did fix up some typos and tested this code and this does work. These are the results for one country item: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23798326/ I got.

Comment: That is bad solution. Reduces scraping efficency,no exceptions proof, not sutable when there is a lots of child items and you plan to insert in DB. Read more in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383499/scrapy-how-to-populate-hierarchic-items-with-multipel-requests)

Comment: @frenzy if you have a better solution feel free to post an answer :)