# Yield Request call produce weird result in recursive method with scrapy

Tags: python, recursion, web-scraping, scrapy, yield

I'm trying to scrap all departures and arrivals in one day from all airports in all country using Python and Scrapy.

The JSON database used by this famous site (flight radar) need to query page by page when departure or arrival is > 100 in one airport. I also compute a timestamp based on an actual day UTC for the query.

I try to create a database with this hierarchy:

```
country 1
 - airport 1
    - departures
      - page 1
      - page ...
    - arrivals
      - page 1
      - page ...
- airport 2
    - departures
      - page 1
      - page ...
    - arrivals
      - page 
      - page ...
...
```

I use two methods to compute timestamp and url query by page :

```
def compute_timestamp(self):
    from datetime import datetime, date
    import calendar
    # +/- 24 heures
    d = date(2017, 4, 27)
    timestamp = calendar.timegm(d.timetuple())
    return timestamp

def build_api_call(self,code,page,timestamp):
    return 'https://api.flightradar24.com/common/v1/airport.json?code={code}&plugin\[\]=&plugin-setting\[schedule\]\[mode\]=&plugin-setting\[schedule\]\[timestamp\]={timestamp}&page={page}&limit=100&token='.format(
        code=code, page=page, timestamp=timestamp)
```

I store result into `CountryItem`, which contain lots of `AirportItem` into airports. My `item.py` is :

```
class CountryItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    num_airports = scrapy.Field()
    airports = scrapy.Field()
    other_url= scrapy.Field()
    last_updated = scrapy.Field(serializer=str)

class AirportItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    code_little = scrapy.Field()
    code_total = scrapy.Field()
    lat = scrapy.Field()
    lon = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    departures = scrapy.Field()
    arrivals = scrapy.Field()
```

My main parse builds a Country item for all countries (i limit here to Israel for example). Next, I yield for each country a `scrapy.Request` to scrape airports.

```
###################################
# MAIN PARSE
####################################
def parse(self, response):
    count_country = 0
    countries = []
    for country in response.xpath('//a[@data-country]'):
        item = CountryItem()
        url =  country.xpath('./@href').extract()
        name = country.xpath('./@title').extract()
        item['link'] = url[0]
        item['name'] = name[0]
        item['airports'] = []
        count_country += 1
        if name[0] == "Israel":
            countries.append(item)
            self.logger.info("Country name : %s with link %s" , item['name'] , item['link'])
            yield scrapy.Request(url[0],meta={'my_country_item':item}, callback=self.parse_airports)
```

This method scrape information for each airport, and also call for each airport a `scrapy.request` with airport url to scrape departures and arrivals :

```
  ###################################
# PARSE EACH AIRPORT
####################################
def parse_airports(self, response):
    item = response.meta['my_country_item']
    item['airports'] = []

    for airport in response.xpath('//a[@data-iata]'):
        url = airport.xpath('./@href').extract()
        iata = airport.xpath('./@data-iata').extract()
        iatabis = airport.xpath('./small/text()').extract()
        name = ''.join(airport.xpath('./text()').extract()).strip()
        lat = airport.xpath("./@data-lat").extract()
        lon = airport.xpath("./@data-lon").extract()
        iAirport = AirportItem()
        iAirport['name'] = self.clean_html(name)
        iAirport['link'] = url[0]
        iAirport['lat'] = lat[0]
        iAirport['lon'] = lon[0]
        iAirport['code_little'] = iata[0]
        iAirport['code_total'] = iatabis[0]

        item['airports'].append(iAirport)

    urls = []
    for airport in item['airports']:
        json_url = self.build_api_call(airport['code_little'], 1, self.compute_timestamp())
        urls.append(json_url)
    if not urls:
        return item

    # start with first url
    next_url = urls.pop()
    return scrapy.Request(next_url, self.parse_schedule, meta={'airport_item': item, 'airport_urls': urls, 'i': 0})
```

With the recursive method `parse_schedule` i add each airport to country item. SO members already [help me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41634126/multiple-nested-request-with-scrapy) on this point.

```
###################################
# PARSE EACH AIRPORT OF COUNTRY
###################################
def parse_schedule(self, response):
        """we want to loop this continuously to build every departure and arrivals requests"""
        item = response.meta['airport_item']
        i = response.meta['i']
        urls = response.meta['airport_urls']

        urls_departures, urls_arrivals = self.compute_urls_by_page(response, item['airports'][i]['name'], item['airports'][i]['code_little'])

        print("urls_departures = ", len(urls_departures))
        print("urls_arrivals = ", len(urls_arrivals))

        ## YIELD NOT CALLED
        yield scrapy.Request(response.url, self.parse_departures_page, meta={'airport_item': item, 'page_urls': urls_departures, 'i':0 , 'p': 0}, dont_filter=True)

        # now do next schedule items
        if not urls:
            yield item
            return
        url = urls.pop()

        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_schedule, meta={'airport_item': item, 'airport_urls': urls, 'i': i + 1})
```

the `self.compute_urls_by_page` method compute correct URLs to retrieve all departure and arrivals for one airport.

```
###################################
# PARSE EACH DEPARTURES / ARRIVALS
###################################
def parse_departures_page(self, response):
    item = response.meta['airport_item']
    p = response.meta['p']
    i = response.meta['i']
    page_urls = response.meta['page_urls']

    print("PAGE URL = ", page_urls)

    if not page_urls:
        yield item
        return
    page_url = page_urls.pop()

    print("GET PAGE FOR  ", item['airports'][i]['name'], ">> ", p)

    jsonload = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    json_expression = jmespath.compile("result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.departures.data")
    item['airports'][i]['departures'] = json_expression.search(jsonload)

    yield scrapy.Request(page_url, self.parse_departures_page, meta={'airport_item': item, 'page_urls': page_urls, 'i': i, 'p': p + 1})
```

Next, the first yield in `parse_schedule` which normally call `self.parse_departure_page` recursive method produces weird results. **Scrapy call this method, but I collect the departures page for only one airport i don't understand why...** I have probably an ordering error in my request or yield source code, so perhaps you could help me to find out.

The complete code is on GitHub https://github.com/IDEES-Rouen/Flight-Scrapping/tree/master/flight/flight_project

You could run it using `scrapy cawl airports` commands.

**Update 1 :**

I try to answer the question alone using `yield from`, without success as you can see answer bottom ... so if you have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Comment**: ... not totally clear ... you call AirportData(response, 1) ... also a little typo here : self.pprint(schedule)

I used `class AirportData` to implement (Limit to 2 Pages and 2 Flights).
**Updated my code, removed `class AirportData`** and added `class Page`.
Should now fullfill all dependencies.

This is **not a** typo, `self.pprint(...` is a `class AirportsSpider Method` used for **Pretty Printing** the object, like the Output shown at the End. I have enhanced `class Schedule` to show the Basic Usage.

---

> **Comment**: What is AirportData in your answer ?

**EDIT**: `class AirportData` removed.
As noted at `# ENDPOINT`, a `Page object` of Flight Data splited for `page.arrivals` and `page.departures`.
(Limited to 2 Pages and 2 Flights)

> ```
> Page = [Flight 1, Flight 1, ... Flight n] 
> schedule.airport['arrivals'] == [Page 1, Page 2, ..., Page n]
> schedule.airport['departures'] == [Page 1, Page 2, ..., Page n]
> ```

---

> **Comment**: ... we have multiples pages which contains multiples departures/arrivals.

Yes, at the time of first Answer I didn't have any `api json` respons to get further.
Now I got response from the `api json` but does not reflect the given `timestamp`, returns from `current date`.
The `api params` looking uncommon, have you a link to the Description?

---

Nevertheless, consider this simplified approach:

**# Page object holding one Page of Arrivals/Departures Flight Data**

```
class Page(object):
    def __init__(self, title, schedule):
        # schedule includes ['arrivals'] or ['departures]
        self.current = schedule['page']['current']
        self.total = schedule['page']['total']

        self.header = '{}:page:{} item:{}'.format(title, schedule['page'], schedule['item'])
        self.flight = []
        for data in schedule['data']:
            self.flight.append(data['flight'])

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.flight
```

**# Schedule object holding one Airport all Pages**

```
class Schedule(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.country = None
        self.airport = None

    def __str__(self):
        arrivals = self.airport['arrivals'][0]
        departures = self.airport['departures'][0]
        return '{}\n\t{}\n\t\t{}\n\t\t\t{}\n\t\t{}\n\t\t\t{}'. \
            format(self.country['name'],
                   self.airport['name'],
                   arrivals.header,
                   arrivals.flight[0]['airline']['name'],
                   departures.header,
                   departures.flight[0]['airline']['name'], )
```

**# PARSE EACH AIRPORT OF COUNTRY**

```
def parse_schedule(self, response):
    meta = response.meta

    if 'airport' in meta:
        # First call from parse_airports
        schedule = Schedule()
        schedule.country = response.meta['country']
        schedule.airport = response.meta['airport']
    else:
        schedule = response.meta['schedule']

    data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    airport = data['result']['response']['airport']

    schedule.airport['arrivals'].append(Page('Arrivals', airport['pluginData']['schedule']['arrivals']))
    schedule.airport['departures'].append(Page('Departures', airport['pluginData']['schedule']['departures']))

    page = schedule.airport['departures'][-1]
    if page.current < page.total:
        json_url = self.build_api_call(schedule.airport['code_little'], page.current + 1, self.compute_timestamp())
        yield scrapy.Request(json_url, meta={'schedule': schedule}, callback=self.parse_schedule)
    else:
        # ENDPOINT Schedule object holding one Airport.
        # schedule.airport['arrivals'] and schedule.airport['departures'] ==
        #   List of Page with List of Flight Data
        print(schedule)
```

**# PARSE EACH AIRPORT**

```
def parse_airports(self, response):
    country = response.meta['country']

    for airport in response.xpath('//a[@data-iata]'):
        name = ''.join(airport.xpath('./text()').extract()[0]).strip()

        if 'Charles' in name:
            meta = response.meta
            meta['airport'] = AirportItem()
            meta['airport']['name'] = name
            meta['airport']['link'] = airport.xpath('./@href').extract()[0]
            meta['airport']['lat'] = airport.xpath("./@data-lat").extract()[0]
            meta['airport']['lon'] = airport.xpath("./@data-lon").extract()[0]
            meta['airport']['code_little'] = airport.xpath('./@data-iata').extract()[0]
            meta['airport']['code_total'] = airport.xpath('./small/text()').extract()[0]

            json_url = self.build_api_call(meta['airport']['code_little'], 1, self.compute_timestamp())
            yield scrapy.Request(json_url, meta=meta, callback=self.parse_schedule)
```

**# MAIN PARSE**

> **Note**: `response.xpath('//a[@data-country]')` returns **all** Countrys **two times**!

```
def parse(self, response):
    for a_country in response.xpath('//a[@data-country]'):
            name = a_country.xpath('./@title').extract()[0]
            if name == "France":
                country = CountryItem()
                country['name'] = name
                country['link'] = a_country.xpath('./@href').extract()[0]

                yield scrapy.Request(country['link'],
                                     meta={'country': country},
                                     callback=self.parse_airports)
```

> **Qutput**: Shorten to **2** Pages and **2** Flights per Page
>
> ```
> France
>     Paris Charles de Gaulle Airport
>         Departures:(page=(1, 1, 7)) 2017-07-02 21:28:00 page:{'current': 1, 'total': 7} item:{'current': 100, 'limit': 100, 'total': 696}
>             21:30 PM    AF1558  Newcastle Airport (NCL) Air France ARJ  Estimated dep 21:30
>             21:30 PM    VY8833  Seville San Pablo Airport (SVQ) Vueling 320 Estimated dep 21:30
>             ... (omitted for brevity)
>         Departures:(page=(2, 2, 7)) 2017-07-02 21:28:00 page:{'current': 2, 'total': 7} item:{'current': 100, 'limit': 100, 'total': 696}
>             07:30 AM    AF1680  London Heathrow Airport (LHR)   Air France 789  Scheduled
>             07:30 AM    SN3628  Brussels Airport (BRU)  Brussels Airlines 733   Scheduled
>             ... (omitted for brevity)
>         Arrivals:(page=(1, 1, 7)) 2017-07-02 21:28:00 page:{'current': 1, 'total': 7} item:{'current': 100, 'limit': 100, 'total': 693}
>             16:30 PM    LY325   Tel Aviv Ben Gurion International Airport (TLV) El Al Israel Airlines B739  Estimated 21:29
>             18:30 PM    AY877   Helsinki Vantaa Airport (HEL)   Finnair E190    Landed 21:21
>             ... (omitted for brevity)
>         Arrivals:(page=(2, 2, 7)) 2017-07-02 21:28:00 page:{'current': 2, 'total': 7} item:{'current': 100, 'limit': 100, 'total': 693}
>             00:15 AM    AF982   Douala International Airport (DLA)  Air France 772  Scheduled
>             23:15 PM    AA44    New York John F. Kennedy International Airport (JFK)    American Airlines B763  Scheduled
>             ... (omitted for brevity)
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 - Scrapy 1.4.0***

Comment: Hi, the json query work i retest it, but you need to run the program on github, i push a version which run (without the `yield from`) on master branch : https://github.com/IDEES-Rouen/Flight-Scrapping

Comment: Hum i'm not sure to understand your output, normally for airport with lot of departures (we could test with French charles de gaucle airport perhaps?) we have multiples pages which contains multiples departures(for example 440 departure = 4 pages with 400 departure + 1 page with 40 departures) , and multiple pages which
 multiples arrivals.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i make a try. What is `AirportData` ? in your answer ? The json of flightradar is not documented, i make some weird reverse engineering. I'm not specialist of timestamp, perhaps it's my fault :(

Comment: Ah, and if we remove the filter on "Charles", we need another one level of `yield` i suppose ?

Comment: Hum this is not totally clear for me, sorry, i understand the objective but in your code you call `AirportData(response, 1)` but i don't see the corresponding python class definition in your code . Or `Page` object is a specific python 3 object ? There is also a little typo here : `self.pprint(schedule)`

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help ! I'm working actually to transform the repository to include a DockerFile :)

Comment: i have a `key error` on `schedule.airport['arrivals'].append(Page('Arrivals', airport['pluginData']['schedule']['arrivals']))`, doesn't find `arrivals`

Comment: I add to  parse_airports : `meta['airport']['departures'] = []` and `meta['airport']['arrivals'] = []`

Comment: Oh, and a very last question @stovfl , how can i yield correctly my final item  (airports with schedule and arrivals) in itemPipeline for mongodb ?

Comment: Hum, there is something i probably don't understand in scrapy behavior at ENDPOINT at this time. My first idea was to return `schedule` or `airport`. But finally, perhaps i need ot create a new `ScheduleItem`  ?

Comment: Oh nothing wrong i suppose, i try to use scrapy `item` / `itemPipeline` method in a first place, but if it's work with add_to_mongo pymongo method, why not, i could try.

Comment: @reyman64: Read Relevant SO Question: [importing JSON to mongoDB using pymongo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43095786/7414759)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, i finally found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991840/recursion-using-yield) on SO ...

When you use a recursive `yield`, you need to use `yield from`. Here one example simplified :

```
airport_list = ["airport1", "airport2", "airport3", "airport4"]

def parse_page_departure(airport, next_url, page_urls):

    print(airport, " / ", next_url)


    if not page_urls:
        return

    next_url = page_urls.pop()

    yield from parse_page_departure(airport, next_url, page_urls)

###################################
# PARSE EACH AIRPORT OF COUNTRY
###################################
def parse_schedule(next_airport, airport_list):

    ## GET EACH DEPARTURE PAGE

    departures_list = ["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"]

    next_departure_url = departures_list.pop()
    yield parse_page_departure(next_airport,next_departure_url, departures_list)

    if not airport_list:
        print("no new airport")
        return

    next_airport_url = airport_list.pop()

    yield from parse_schedule(next_airport_url, airport_list)

next_airport_url = airport_list.pop()
result = parse_schedule(next_airport_url, airport_list)

for i in result:
    print(i)
    for d in i:
        print(d)
```

**UPDATE, Don't WORK with real program :**

I try to reproduce the same `yield from` pattern [with the real program here](https://github.com/IDEES-Rouen/Flight-Scrapping/blob/master/flight/flight_project/spiders/AirportsSpider.py), but i have an error using it on `scrapy.Request`, don't understand why...

Here the python traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/reyman/.pyenv/versions/venv352/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/home/reyman/.pyenv/versions/venv352/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/home/reyman/.pyenv/versions/venv352/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/home/reyman/.pyenv/versions/venv352/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/reyman/.pyenv/versions/venv352/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/home/reyman/Projets/Flight-Scrapping/flight/flight_project/spiders/AirportsSpider.py", line 209, in parse_schedule
    yield from scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_schedule, meta={'airport_item': item, 'airport_urls': urls, 'i': i + 1})
TypeError: 'Request' object is not iterable
2017-06-27 17:40:50 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-06-27 17:40:50 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
```

Comment: All your `parse_*` methods are kinda strange, you mix `return` and `yield` there. Did you mean to `raise StopIteration` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I tried cloning locally and investigate a little better, but when it gets to the departure parsing I got some ConnectionRefused error so I am not sure my proposed answer will fix it, anyhow:

```
###################################
# PARSE EACH AIRPORT OF COUNTRY
###################################
def parse_schedule(self, response):
    """we want to loop this continuously to build every departure and arrivals requests"""
    item = response.meta['airport_item']
    i = response.meta['i']
    urls = response.meta['airport_urls']

    urls_departures, urls_arrivals = self.compute_urls_by_page(response, item['airports'][i]['name'], item['airports'][i]['code_little'])

    if 'urls_departures' in response.meta:
        urls_departures += response.meta["urls_departures"]

    if 'urls_arrivals' in response.meta:
        urls_arrivals += response.meta["urls_arrivals"]

    print("urls_departures = ", len(urls_departures))
    print("urls_arrivals = ", len(urls_arrivals))
    item['airports'][i]['departures'] = []

    # now do next schedule items
    if not urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(urls_departures.pop(), self.parse_departures_page, meta={'airport_item': item, 'page_urls': urls_departures, 'i':i , 'p': 0}, dont_filter=True)
    else:
        url = urls.pop()

        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_schedule, meta={'airport_item': item, 'airport_urls': urls, 'i': i + 1, 'urls_departures': urls_departures, 'urls_arrivals': urls_arrivals})

###################################
# PARSE EACH DEPARTURES / ARRIVALS
###################################
def parse_departures_page(self, response):
    item = response.meta['airport_item']
    p = response.meta['p']
    i = response.meta['i']
    page_urls = response.meta['page_urls']

    jsonload = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
    json_expression = jmespath.compile("result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.departures.data")

    # Append a new page
    item['airports'][i]['departures'].append(json_expression.search(jsonload))

    if len(page_urls) > 0:
        page_url = page_urls.pop()

        yield scrapy.Request(page_url, self.parse_departures_page, meta={'airport_item': item, 'page_urls': page_urls, 'i': i, 'p': p + 1}, dont_filter=True)
    else:
        yield item
```

But basically these are your mistakes:

1. In your parse_schedule and on your parse_departures_page you have conditions for yielding the final item;
2. You are passing the wrong url to parse_departures_page;
3. You need dont_filter=True on parse_departures_page;
4. You are trying to keep a lot of loops for parsing more information to the same object

My proposed changes will keep track of all urls_departures on this airport so that you can iterate over then on parse_departures_page and should fix your problem.

Even if this fix your problem I REALLY recommend you change your data structure so that you can have multiple items for departures and be able to extract this information more efficiently.